# ExtJs5 + Spinnerfield + Touch devices

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, extjs5, sencha-touch-theming

I'm working on migrate a project Ext4 -> Ext5.
Beta users reasonable noticed, that current spinner fields with up&down triangles on touch devices are very hard to be used. They has small sizes and it will be much better to have (-) and (+) buttons rights instead.
Basically it is already done in Sencha Touch 2.4 or early and (in theory) may borrow (s)css from touch themes to ExtJS

I wonder may somebody did this trick ? Or maybe there is a separate component?

Answer (score 0):

meantime the issue is solved and it is very simple. Just need to use `ext-neptune-touch' or 'ext-crisp-touch' themes to get triangles away.